# GCP Dataflow Quickstart error running WordCount example: Unknown lifecycle phase ".mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount"

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to go through the "Quickstart Using Java" for GCP Cloud Dataflow from here https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven and am getting an error in the "Run WordCount locally" step.

Running this at a PowerShell prompt

`PS C:\apache-maven-3.6.2\word-count-beam> mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount -Dexec.args="--output=.\output\"`

I receive a BUILD FAILURE message with:

> [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]

When I add -e I also get the stack trace:

> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateLifecycleMappings (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:248)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:217)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:126)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)

I am using jdk-13.0.1 and maven 3.6.2 and have setup JAVA_HOME and added JAVA_HOME\Bin and Maven to my PATH.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: How did you perform the build?

Comment: Like this, using maven: mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount -Dexec.args="--output=.\output\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are using `JDK-13.0.1` whereas `Apache Beam` currently supports `Java 8`. Below are the pre-requisites for Java and Maven.

1. Download and install the Java Development Kit (JDK) version 8. Verify that the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set and points to your JDK installation.
2. Download and install Apache Maven by following Maven's installation guide for your specific operating system.

Once you have done the installs for Java and Maven, you can get the code using the following command

```
mvn archetype:generate \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.beam \
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=beam-sdks-java-maven-archetypes-examples \
      -DarchetypeVersion=2.16.0 \
      -DgroupId=org.example \
      -DartifactId=word-count-beam \
      -Dversion="0.1" \
      -Dpackage=org.apache.beam.examples \
      -DinteractiveMode=false
```

To run the code locally

```
cd word-count-beam/

mvn compile exec:java \
      -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount \
      -Dexec.args="--output=./output/"
```

Comment: Thanks Jayadeep. That was it. I deleted the Maven directory and started the tutorial with Java 8 setup and the example app is working for me now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using powershell, then instead of "-Dexec.mainClass" use "-D exec.mainClass"